# Read input until the value is < 0

Tags: arrays, input, fortran

There are plenty of implementations for any other language but not Fortran, and I was not able to adopt from them.

```
Sample Input:
5 10 15 20 25 0
Output:
Array: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

Sample Input:
5
10
15
20
25
0
Output:
Array: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Both types of input should work (one-line and multiple lines).

So, what I've tried is implied do loop (because I know exactly that I can read up to N values); however, I could not find a way to stop reading if the input is 0 or any other value.

---

### What I've tried already

This piece of code clearly does not read values from one line:

```
do while (.not.input<0)
    read *, input
end do
```

And this one does not continue until implied do-loop ends

```
do while (.not.input<0)
    read *, (x(i), i=1, 10)
    input = x(i)
end do
```

Comment: Non-advancing I/O is the way forward here. Do you know the format of the numbers?

Comment: @IanBush , yes, an integer (0<n<100; I guess that is I3)

Comment: If you know the format of the numbers (and that means each number and the spaces between them - can you provide a Fortran format which will read a line with, say, 4 numbers in it?)) as I hint above this is fairly easy using non-advancing I/O. If not, it's not. You'll have to read in as a character one as a time and parse as you go.  This is because Fortran I/O is record base which is different to how many other languages work. In most cases I find it more powerful and preferable than viewing a file as a byte stream, but it does make this more difficult.

Comment: @IanBush, the thing is that program does not involve any external files. There's a very detailed instruction in Intel's Fortran Compiler documentation, but not for "keyboard typing", unfortunately.

Comment: You can still provide a format for reading from the "keyboard"  - Fortran makes no distinction whatsoever between that and a file and indeed a printer.

Comment: Ahhh well, if you are keying the numbers in at run time you could make your life easier by sticking to one input style or the other; probably one integer per line.

Comment: Agreed - the "fortran way" is not this heresy

Comment: Is input defined to be an integer? Or do you use implicit types? Did you initialize it to some value >= 0 so the loop even starts in the first place? Also, in your example there simply isn't any input < 0, so it would never atually stop in this case.

Comment: It looks like your input expects "0" to be the limiter, not a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

This program accepts input from stdin.  You can put more than 1 integer on a line separated by a space. The line can end with 0, e.g., 10 20 30 0.  You can also enter 1 integer per line with the final line being 0.  A blank line is an not allowed.

```
   program foo
   character(len=3) :: fmt = '(A)'
   character(len=80) s, t
   integer :: m=0
   integer, allocatable :: n(:)
   allocate(n(0))
   do
   read(*,fmt) s
5  call get_token(s,t)
   if (len_trim(s) == 0 .and. len_trim(t) == 0) goto 30
   read(t,*,err=15) i
   if (i == 0) goto 20
   n = [n,i]
   m = m + 1
   if (len_trim(s) /= 0) goto 5
   end do
15 write(*,fmt) 'conversion issue'
   goto 40
30 write(*,fmt) 'blank line'
   goto 40
20 if (m == 0) then
   write (*,fmt) 'no elements'
   goto 40
   end if
   write(s,'(I0)') m
   s = '(' // trim(s) // '(I0,1X))'
   write(*,s) n
40 if (allocated(n)) deallocate(n)
   contains
   subroutine get_token(str, token)
   character(len=*), intent(inout) :: str
   character(len=*), intent(out) :: token
   j = scan(trim(str), ' ');
   if (j /= 0) then
   token = str(1:j)
   str = adjustl(str(j:len_trim(str)))
   else
   token = trim(str)
   str = ''
   end if
   end subroutine get_token
   end program foo
```

There may be a bug or two.  Ah, there was a bug!  Nothing like a last minute small change to throw a wrench into the mix.